# shouldAutorotate return true but doesn't rotate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

My first view controller is LoginViewController. I'm trying to support autorotate management on iOS 6.

I've implemented shouldAutorotate instead of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, like this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

   return [DeviceSupport isOrientationSupported:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

`shouldAutorotate` is called five times at the launch of application. toInterfaceOrientation values are, in order and without changing ipad orientation : 0, 0, 0, 4 and 4. First, why app take so long time to put the right orientation in the currentDevice? And why shouldAutorotate is called five times?

When orientation is 4, `[DeviceSupport isOrientationSupported:toInterfaceOrientation]` return true. But my app does not rotate.

In my info.plist :

```
Supported interface orientations
=> Item 0: Portrait (bottom home button)
=> Item 1: Portrait (top home button)

Supported interface orientations (iPad)
=> Item 0: Landscape (left home button)
=> Item 1: Landscape (right home button)
```

Any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you code from:

```
[self.window addSubview:aController.view];
```

to this code:

```
self.window.rootViewController = aController;
```

Also add the following methods for orientation support

shouldAutorotate -return YES

supportedInterfaceOrientations- return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;

Comment: LoginViewController is the first controller in my storyboard. I do not manage how it's added as rootviewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks Shantanu, i missed the part on `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. It works :)

Comment: Excellent! that was precisely my problem... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Could you double-check that you implemented supportedInterfaceOrientations as well?

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```